# How to pack a button in custom area of window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python. I am using python 3.10 version. I created a window with two buttons using tkinter. I need to place the buttons in custom area rather than any sides which tkinter choose. I dont want to use "place" method. How to place the buttons with specific coordinates using pack?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import *

core = Tk()

core.geometry("640x360")
core.title("txteditor")

diffbtn = Button(text = "Check Difference")
# If i use place, then i can choose a custom area in the window
# diffbtn.place(x = 200, y = 5, height = 30, width = 150)
diffbtn.pack(padx = 200, pady = 20)

diffbtn1 = Button(text = "Check Difference")
# diffbtn.place(x = 200, y = 5, height = 30, width = 150)
diffbtn1.pack(side = TOP,pady = 20)

core.mainloop()
```

Edit:

When the tkinter window is expanded to right side, the button does not move with the window with place. How to pin the button with the window during expansion or collapse of the window?

[image]

Comment: `pack()` *is not designed to used like that*. It is what `place()` is designed for.

Comment: But if i use place, then the widgets are looking clumsy and overlap each other, when the window is shrinked or expanded.

Comment: If you use absolute position and size in `place()` properly, they won't overlap each other when the window is resized.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "a custom area"? Where do you want them? Bottom line is that you must use `place` if you want widgets at specific coordinates, but both `pack` and `grid` are generally better for creating a responsive UI. I probably use `place` once for every thousand or so times I use `grid` or `pack`.

Comment: @BryanOakley - How to pin the button with the window during expansion or collapse of the window with place option?

Comment: Your best bet is to use `pack` or `grid`. Why do you need a precise pixel placement? Where do you want the buttons to be?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve. I'm guessing you want the buttons in the upper-right portion of the window. In that case I would use frames to divide the UI into two sections, with the buttons in a right section and whatever else you want on the left.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=400, height=400)
button_frame.pack(side="right", fill="y")
main_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

diffbtn = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Check Difference")
diffbtn1 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Check Difference")

diffbtn.pack(side="top", pady=20)
diffbtn1.pack(side="top", pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot using pack - narrow]
[image: screenshot using pack - wide]

If you want to use `place`, you should use relative positioning. You can use `relx` and `rely` to position the widget relative to some portion of the window. The value 0 (zero) means the top and left, and the value 1.0 means bottom and right. To center a widget you would use .5

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

diffbtn = tk.Button(root, text="Check Difference")
diffbtn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Check Difference")

diffbtn.place(relx=1.0, anchor="ne", x=-10, y = 20)
diffbtn1.place(relx=1.0, anchor="ne", x=-10, y = 100)

root.mainloop()
```

Breakdown of the arguments in the first use of `place`:

- `relx=1.0` - place the widget relative to the right edge of the window
- `anchor="ne"` - place the north-east corner of the widget at the requested coordinates
- `x=-10` - place the ne corner of the widget minus 10 pixels from the relative position (10 pixels to the left of the right edge)
- `y=20` - place the widget 20 pixels from the top of the window (the default for `rely` is 0 - relative to the top of the window).

[image: screenshot using place - narrow]
[image: screenshot using place - wide]